# Cpanel not allowing Javascript to access images

Tags: javascript, cpanel

I've tried googling how to do this for a while now including changing permissions and ect. but none of this has seemed to work. My current problem is that I have a bit of Javascript code that will display all .png files from a folder named Uploads. The script works when I try to use it on my localhost however, when I try to use it using Cpanel, nothing happens. When I visit the website that Cpanel is running and use Google Chrome's Inspect Element, a error pops up that says `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)` even though I've changed the folder and images' permissions to `755`.

**Code:**

```
var folder = "Uploads/";
            $.ajax({
                url : folder,
                success: function (data) {
                    $(data).find("a").attr("href", function (i, val) {
                        if (val.match(/\.jpg|\.png|\.gif/)) { 
                            $("#Main").append( "<img style='box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px grey;' src='"+ folder + val +"'><br><br>");
                        } 
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Maybe you didn't change the permission on the images/files inside the "Uploads" folder?

Comment: Are you using a content management system at all on the website? I found earlier subfolders on wordpress can have trouble.

Comment: I changed the permission on the images/files as well

Comment: can you access the image directly from the browser? IE mywebpage.com/folder/img1.png

Comment: Actually the real error says that it doesn't have permission to go into the Uploads folder, and another thing is that I can go to mywebpage.com/folder/img1.png however it gives me a 403 error when I go to mywebpage.com/folder

Comment: Ok. Well I some how got the 403 error to go away now It's just that the images won't load.